# Convert current age into a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

i can get the current age from date of birth. But i have a requirment where  i need to convert the current age into a number with two decimal places.

for example: 36 years and 6 months and 15 days should be 36.55.

how can i do this ?

Comment: for me is not a number

Comment: When 6months/12(total months) =.5 and same way 15days/30days =.5 ,what happens when the month have 31,28 or 29?

Comment: Following the comment by @K.K, is it really meaningful to have a fraction of a month as a metric for age?

Comment: 36.5.5 is not a number, really. You can use varchar for that formatting.

Comment: sorry guys i have updated the question. for some reason they want it like that. good one KK how about rounding it up in some way a rough figure will do

Comment: You have this tagged as [tag:sql]. Do you get this age from the database in a single field? Is it a string?

Comment: it is a parameter sent  to a stored proc. the datatype is date

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output, it will be very helpful to all of us rather than rambling on discussion.

Comment: 01-nov-1979 =36.48,   18-dec -2008 = 7.33,  30-may-13 = 2.88

Comment: Rinu, What is the fraction? How can the first of November have a fraction of `.48` and a day in May have `.88`?

Comment: could you explain the calculation?  It makes sense in terms of months and years, but what are you dividing the days by to get a decimal?  Not all months have the same number of days, and you need to tell us how to handle that.

Comment: actually try my SQL, I think it is logical to work out the age attained in months, then divide by 12 and add on the days as a further decimal fraction - they might need this for actuarial calculations by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

Use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, birthday, GETDATE()) / 365.25 AS DECIMAL (10,2))
FROM yourTable
```

This calculates the number of days between the birth date and now, converts to number of years, and then rounds that figure to two decimal places.

Here is what your script might look like:

```
DECLARE @dateOfBirth DATETIME
SET @dateOfBirth = '1987-05-25'
DECLARE @age DECIMAL (10, 2)
SET @age = (SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateOfBirth, GETDATE()) / 365.25 AS DECIMAL (10,2))
            FROM yourTable)
```

Comment: can i do something like this ? DECLARE @ dateOfBirth1 DATETIME
SET @ dateOfBirth1 = '05/25/1987'
DECLARE @ age DECIMAL (10,2)
SET age = CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @ dateOfBirth1, GETDATE()) / 365.25 AS DECIMAL (10,2))

Comment: i need to get this into a variable for some reason it throws an exception Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Use `SET @age = ...`, and set it to the `SELECT` result.

Comment: if you get a person born 1st March 2016, his age is going to come up as less than 1 on 1st March 2017

Comment: @AndrewDeighton What is wrong about that?  In conversational English we typically refer to a baby less than one year old as a "X months old."  If this be a concern, let the OP clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below script.

```
DECLARE @year INT =36
DECLARE @month INT=6
DECLARE @day INT=15
```

If you want `36.5.5`

```
SELECT CAST(@year+CAST(ROUND((@month+0.00)/12.0,1)as numeric(18,1)) as VARCHAR(10))+RIGHT(CAST(CAST(ROUND((@day+0.00)/30.0,1)as numeric(18,1)) as VARCHAR(10)),2)
```

If you want `36.55`

```
SELECT CAST(@year+CAST(ROUND((@month+0.00)/12.0,1)as numeric(18,1)) as VARCHAR(10))+RIGHT(CAST(CAST(ROUND((@day+0.00)/30.0,1)as numeric(18,1)) as VARCHAR(10)),1)
```

sample output :

[image]

Comment: where does the idea he wants 36.5.5 come from?  Did he really say that somewhere?  But good luck to all if he wants that!

Comment: @Andrew Deighton : at first he was asking like that..:) so just included.

Comment: This is something that i was looking for. Thanks Unnikrishan and all for your help for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1) calculates whole number (curtate age in months)

2) calculates balance of days

3) age is then (age in months) / 12 + (extra days) / 365.2425

where 365.2425 is what I calculated as the average number of days in a year

```
DECLARE @DOB date = '1966-04-23';
DECLARE @CALCDATE date = '2016-09-15';

--
SELECT 
      (DATEDIFF(month, @DOB, @CALCDATE) - CASE WHEN DAY(@DOB) > DAY(@CALCDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 12.0 + 
      DATEDIFF(day, 
                    DATEADD(month, 
                    datediff(month,@DOB, @CALCDATE) - CASE WHEN DAY(@DOB) > DAY(@CALCDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                    @dob), 
                @CALCDATE) / 365.2425
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to calculate the months to the days and get the decimals by proportion to the 365 (problem with the leap year, depends how accurate you want to be). The different days count in the month can be handled easily if you have the birth date stored somewhere (or also, take the 30 value as the approximation)